# Obtener registro aleatorias de manera que salgan mas veces los que tengan mas prioridad

Tags: mysql, sql

Actualmente tengo unas imágenes y cada ves que recargo me sale una imagen de manera aleatoria todo bien , pero quisiera que dentro de la aleatoriedad al mostrar las imágenes , cuanta mas prioridad, más probabilidades habrá de que salga más veces.
Una imagen con prioridad 15 se mostrará más veces que una con prioridad 6

intente esta consulta en mysql pero siempre me sale el mismo resultado y es obvio por que es DESC pero no hace el random

```
SELECT * FROM `banners` 
WHERE enabled = 1 
ORDER BY `banners`.`priority` DESC , RAND()
```

Que solución podría realizar puedo hacerlo con php  y mysql pero he leído e intentado y nada.

Comment: Suena bien el planteamiento del problema, sin embargo, debes de recordar que el RAND() toma un registro aleatorio desde tu registro 1 hasta el último registro, puesto que no puedes controlar, creo, realmente cuál sale o no independientemente de tu prioridad. Lo que yo te recomiendo es usar un LIMIT como de 5 registros con más prioridad y a esos hacerle un RAND(), de otra manera lo veo complicado

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que te esta ordenando por prioridad en primer lugar, los que sean prioridad X siempre van a aparecer juntos, con orden aleatorio por el `rand()`  pero siempre juntos. Lo que quieres hacer requiere una función random con pesos o probabilidades para cada prioridad. Dudo que haya algo así en el motor. Lo que sí podrías hacer es tener un % de probabilidad por cada prioridad y multiplicar este por `rand()` en el orden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo mucha experiencia con MySQL, por lo que el código podría ser mejorado, pero esta es una adaptación de lo que haría en SQL Server.

Necesitas unir tu tabla con una tabla de números para multiplicar las filas por la prioridad que tenga cada una. De esa forma puedes aumentar la probabilidad de que aparezca cada una.

No limito los resultados para que puedas ver como cambia el orden.

```
SELECT * FROM `banners` 
JOIN (SELECT x.n*10+y.n AS n
      FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) x
      CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) y) t ON `priority` >= t.`n`
WHERE enabled = 1 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Dejo también [el fiddle que usé para probar](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c97fec/4/0).

La otra opción que se comentó es la de tener un porcentaje por el cual se pueda multiplicar el dato aleatorio para mostrar la prioridad. Dependiendo de los datos podría ser más eficiente ya que requiere de menos información.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * , (priority + 100.) / (SELECT SUM(priority) FROM `banners` WHERE enabled = 1) AS priority_perc
      FROM `banners` 
      WHERE enabled = 1) t 
ORDER BY RAND() * priority_perc
```

Comment: WOO esto si que es largo, no tengo tanto dominio en mysql pero lo analice y funciona , muchas gracias amigo, también estaba probando crearlo con php, pero como que es mas  complicado , usando las funciones mt_rand o rand , tendría que crear un porcentaje a cada registro y luego crear un azar por porcentaje mas alto umm

Comment: Si tienes una tabla de números, podrías utilizarla en vez de crearla en cada consulta. O podrías usar una vista que cree la tabla al vuelo.

Comment: Si ya veo para crear la parte de los números o mejor dicho multiplicarlo  se pone largo el código, estaba simulando creando desde php y lo vi largo y con mas código. Inclusive hice algo propio con php para realizar un random entre porcentaje , obtener los de mas prioridad , los que le siguen y los de menos prioridad cuando el  numero 1 está más repetido y tiene una probabilidad del 60% de salir y obtener los 4 con mas prioridad y hacer un random entre esos 4 , en cualquier caso tu solución me es mucho mas útil la analizare más a fondo y muchas gracias!

Comment: Dejé una alternativa adicional que maneja la opción del porcentaje. Es buena idea y no es tan complicado llevarla a cabo.

Comment: Si woo buena alternativa, muchas gracias, voy a ver como puedo realizar para sacar los de mejor porcentaje, aunque si vemos el que es mas exacto es el de repetir los registros pero eso veo que consume tanto en php como en mysql si son mas de 300  o 400 registros , muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

`RAND()` es un generador de números pseudo aleatorio y uniforme, eso quiere decir, que si queremos obtener un número aleatorio del 1 al 10 y hacemos: `SELECT FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 10));` obtendremos ese número, pero la probabilidad es uniforme en todo el conjunto, cada número del 1 al 10 tiene las mismas chances de salir. Por esto, `RAND()` por si solo no te sirve ya que el "desorden aleatorio" será uniforme.

Lo que puedes hacer es usar `priority` para hacer un random relativo (con peso), si el valor de la prioridad es ordinal (es una escala) y no tienes una priordad `0`, el orden podría aplicarse así:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM banners
       WHERE enabled = 1 
       ORDER BY RAND() * priority DESC
```

Comment: Esta manera esta genial aunque veo que sale mas las prioridades altas y las bajas como un 5% , pero en php se puede adaptar , muchas gracias , en este caso veo que estas multiplicando la prioridad de cada registro? Osea como un juego de azar si hay una priodad 20 este registro estaria multiplicado por 20 y la posibilidad de salir seria mas alta no? No he realizado tantas operaciones matematicas en mysql

Comment: Estrictamente hablando, es un orden aleatorio ponderado por un peso, en este caso la prioridad, si la prioridad es un numero correlativo, el peso es equilibrado y las chances deberían ir decayendo entre cada prioridad de forma mas o menos uniforme. También podrías ajustar cada prioridad y darle un peso especifico, para aumentar las chances de ciertas prioridades. Te aclaro igual que no es un ajuste probabilístico real, pero es una forma simple de lograr lo que buscas y que insume pocos recurso